# How to dump all the XMM registers in gdb?

Tags: x86, gdb, simd, sse, cpu-registers

I can dump the all the integer registers in gdb with just:

```
info registers
```

for the xmm registers (intel) I need a file like:

```
print $xmm0
print $xmm1
...
print $xmm15
```

and then source that file.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Semi-related: MMX registers work less easily in GDB, because they alias with the x87 stack regs: [why does GDB not tab-complete mmx register name(mm0-mm7)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68109381)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(gdb) apropos registers
collect -- Specify one or more data items to be collected at a tracepoint
core-file -- Use FILE as core dump for examining memory and registers
info all-registers -- List of all registers and their contents
...
```

The last one is the one you want.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949827/50617) below.

Comment: I'd tried apropos xmm, but didn't think of registers.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to dump just MMX registers? `info mmx` and `info mmx-registers` did not work for me. I guess I ask, is it all or nothing? Otherwise, that pager stops my workflow.

Comment: @jww: `info reg vec` dumps the full-width registers, which could be cluttered if they're ZMM or YMM but you're only working on code that uses the XMM low 128-bits.

Answer (score 8):

The fine [manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html) says:

```
(gdb) info all-registers
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to print out only the xmm registers then you can use `info registers sse` (or the abbreviation `i r sse` or even `i r s`).

Similarly to print out only the fpu registers you can use `info registers float` (or `i r f`).

(In the above commands, `sse` and `float` are [*register groups*](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Maintenance-Commands.html), which you can list using `maintenance print reggroups`.)

Comment: `info reg vec` dumps their full width, e.g. YMM or ZMM on systems that support that.