# why does GDB not tab-complete mmx register name(mm0-mm7)

Tags: gdb, x86-64, cpu-registers, mmx

I use gdb `info registers <tab>` to see all the registers, but I don't see MMX registers.

[image: gdb i r tab, without mmx register mm0-mm7]

My CPU is Xeon Platinum 8163, a modern Xeon cpu that supports SSE and MMX. So i think its a gdb problem(if i am right).

Why does gdb not support showing mmx register while mmx register should be of same importance level compared to basic registers and sse registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks a lot for your editing my question. And your typing style has helpfully influenced me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MMX registers don't have their own separate architectural state; they alias the x87 registers st0..st7.  (Intel did this so OSes wouldn't to special support to save/restore the MMX state on context switch via FXSAVE/FXRSTOR).  That's different from all the other registers.

But I think this is a GDB bug, not an intentional decision to not expose the MMX state except via the x87 state.  `info reg mmx` tab-completes but prints nothing.  (GDB 10.1 on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux)

Even when running a program with the FPU in MMX state (after executing `movd mm0, eax` for example), it still doesn't tab complete.  In fact, even `p $mm0` just prints void (because that GDB variable name isn't recognized as being tied to an MMX register).

---

**You *can* see the MMX state via `i r float`**

e.g. after `mov eax, 231` / `movd mm0, eax`,

```
 starti
 stepi
 si

(gdb) p $mm0
$1 = void
(gdb) i r mm0
Invalid register `mm0'
(gdb) i r mmx
(gdb) i r float
st0            <invalid float value> (raw 0xffff00000000000000e7)
st1            0                   (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
...
```

After another single step, of `pshufw mm1, mm0, 0`

```
(gdb) si
0x000000000040100c in ?? ()
(gdb) i r float
st0            <invalid float value> (raw 0xffff00000000000000e7)
st1            <invalid float value> (raw 0xffff00e700e700e700e7)
st2            0                   (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
```

So if you ignore the high 16 bits of the 80-bit extended precision bit-pattern, you can look at the 64-bit mantissa part as the MMX register value.

I assume this has gone unfixed for so long because SSE2 makes MMX *mostly* obsolete, providing more wider registers and not needing a slow `emms` to leave MMX state before a potential x87 FPU instruction like `fld`.  (And on modern CPUs like Skylake, MMX instructions don't have mov-elimination, and some run on fewer execution ports than their SSE2 equivalents, like `paddd`)

Of course, some existing code, notably x264 and FFmpeg's h.264 software decoder, still use hand-written MMX asm instead of the low qword of an XMM register.  This is sometimes advantageous, e.g. to allow `punpcklbw mm0, [rdi]`.

BTW, the test program I single-stepped was assembled + linked from this NASM source into a static executable:

```
mov    eax, 231         ; __NR_exit_group = 0xe7
movd   mm0, eax
pshufw mm1, mm0, 0      ; broadcast the low word
emms
nop

syscall
```

Comment: Thanks for your profound  answer. It reveals a workaround to use st0-st7 register's lower 64 bits to represent mmx0-mmx7 register in GDB.